# How to send data to iOS by use of PAN

Tags: ios, bluetooth, data-transfer, external-accessory, mfi

We are looking for a bluetooth solution to send 18Mb of data from some kind of sensor to an iPhone/iPad.

Bluetooth Low Energy is way to slow for this (4kb/s or something like that). Using classical Bluetooth however, requires an MFI program (Made For iPhone/iPad) enrolment. But for some default supported protocols in which PAN (Personal Area Network) this MFI enrolment isn't needed.

I spend the whole day doing research on the internet but couldnt find a implementation of PAN data transfer between a device and an iOS app. I am hoping I can somehow connect to a bluetooth device and send serial data to my app. So my last hope is (again) StackOverflow.

Does any of you have an implementation or example or at least a way to solve this problem?

Comment: What device? Is your problem finding an implementation for the device, or IOS, or both? It's really not that clear what you are asking. How about the Serial Port Profile (SPP)? That is one of the most basic of profiles for connecting two BT devices and should be supported by almost all devices. If you truly want PAN profile support then you need to describe your device.

Comment: The device is yet to be build. Is SPP supported over classical bluetooth (not low energy) without MFI certification?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, using SPP requires MFi certification. Also, you'll need to possess an MFi license to get access to the documentation.